# Ajax BeginForm posting to an action that returns json, IE tries to download it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, internet-explorer-8

Here is the code I am using to setup the form:

```
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveCroppedPhoto", new { Id = Model.memberId.GetValueOrDefault() }, new AjaxOptions
                                                                {
                                                                    OnBegin = "ProfileOnBegin",
                                                                    OnComplete = "ProfileOnComplete",
                                                                    OnFailure = "ProfileOnFailure",
                                                                    OnSuccess = "ProfileOnSuccess"
                                                                }, new { id = "cropPhotoForm" })) {%>
```

My action result returns a json result as follow:

```
 return Json(new { success });
```

In IE8 when the action returns, it tries to download the result.  The content type coming back is application/json.  Anyone have any idea how to stop IE from trying to download the result?

Some additional info:
I just noticed in fiddler that when I am saving, two requests are made to the action.  Trying to figure that out now.  I am guessing that is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to call $(frm).submit() and so it was causing the ajax post plus a regular post.  That is why it was trying to download the json.  My bad.

I solved this by appending a hidden submit button to the form and firing the click event in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch on unobtrusive ajax via:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```